# Batching in NHibernate for Informix database

Tags: nhibernate

Im using Fluent NHibernate for Informix database. I need to use batching concept for bulk insert and update. Can anyone give me suggestion for that. I found out that by default batching in Nhibernate supports only SQL and Oracle. By anyway we override it and also support informix?

Answer (score 1):

I know this does not directly answer your question but somebody has provided a patch for batching in MySql. You may be able to take this patch and apply the logic for Informix.

Link to patch is on [NHibernate Jira](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2778)